# Stuck in regex to detect URL for particular domain in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find out a URL which belongs to :

```
http://domain.blob.core.windows.net/ 
https://domain.blob.core.windows.net/

http://domain.blob.core.windows.net
https://domain.blob.core.windows.net
```

The regex which I wrote

```
Regex reg2= new Regex(@"^http(s?)://[0-9a-zA-Z](.blob.core.windows.net)(/?)$");
string url = "http://abc.blob.core.windows.net";
        if(reg2.IsMatch(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
```

I am not able to find the match. It's not working :( I am pretty weak in regex. So can anyone help me to find out my mistake? I am using c#. It always prints no.

UPDATE : FINAL Answer which worked for me:

```
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]*(\.blob\.core\.windows\.net)
(/?)$");
```

Just in case anybody needs something like this :)

Comment: Your `.`'s are not escaped...

Comment: Try pasting your regex string into an expression analyser. Expresso is a decent one and was free last time I used it.

Comment: thanks leppie , thanks phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with `"^http(s?)://[0-9a-zA-Z](.blob.core.windows.net)(/?)$"` however `[0-9a-zA-Z]` should be `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` as you want to be multiple characters before `.blob.core.windows.net` not just a single character.

Note: you don't need brackets here if you not capturing parts of the match, the optional operator is applied to the previous character only so `^https?$` matches `'http'` or `'https'` and not `''` as only the `s` is optional, Also escape all `.` characters as in `regex` the `.` characters matches any single character so to match a literal `.` you want `\.`.

```
"^https?://[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.blob\.core\.windows\.net/?$"
```

Comment: thanks a lot @sudo_O it helped me :) worked!! :) I can't accept answer for 5 mins.. i will asap :) Just one thing I want to mention

    Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+(.blob.core.windows.net)(/?)$");

this is what I used. Thanks Phil and sudo_O both :)

Comment: Hell yea @leppie what do I do then :(

Comment: @leppie I added info on escaping `.`

Comment: @Mandy: Escape the `.` with a \ EG `blob\.core\.`

Comment: @leppie 

`Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]*(\.blob\.core\.windows\.net)(/?)$");`

Worked